# Modifying \autoref to behave (somewhat) like \vref

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

I would like to modify the `\autoref` command in the following way: if the `\autoref` command and the label are on the same page, it behaves like `\autoref*` (i.e., no hyperlink). Else, it behaves usually.

Thanks, Vishnu

Comment: `varioref` also has a `\labelformat` command, which is worth looking into. It adds names of section types (e.g. chapter, section, subsection ...) to the `\vref`s output.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a quick&dirty solution that works but throws strange error messages if a label is undefined. If you comment the `\pagebreak` out, then the link goes away.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\aref}[1]{%
    \edef\cur@page{\thepage}%
    \edef\ref@page{\csname r@#1\endcsname}%
    \edef\ref@page{\expandafter\@secondoffive\ref@page}%
    \ifx\cur@page\ref@page
      \autoref*{#1}%
    \else
      \autoref{#1}%
    \fi }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

We have
\begin{equation}\label{myeq}
a=b.
\end{equation}

\pagebreak

In~\aref{myeq} \dots

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Hendrik Vogt's answer, but using the expandable `\getpagerefnumber` from `refcount` (which is part of the `hyperref` bundle anyway!) (I used his example, however!)

I've redefined `\autoref` to provide the feature instead of using a new macro name for this.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}%
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\LetLtxMacro\hyperref@@autoref\autoref%

\AtBeginDocument{%
\RenewDocumentCommand{\autoref}{sm}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
    \hyperref@@autoref*{#2}%
  }{%
    \edef\@currentpage{\thepage}%
    \edef\pageoflabel{\getpagerefnumber{#2}}%
    \ifx\@currentpage\pageoflabel
    \hyperref@@autoref*{#2}%
    \else
    \hyperref@@autoref{#2}%
    \fi
  }%
}
}

\makeatother

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{First section}
We have in \autoref{myeq} some important stuff, but see \autoref{secondsection} too!
\begin{equation}\label{myeq}
a=b.
\end{equation} 



\clearpage

In~\autoref{myeq} \dots

\blindtext[5]


\section{Another section}\label{secondsection}

Some reference: \autoref{secondsection}

\blindtext[5]

\end{document}
```

[image]